# Python - TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable and other errors

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to create a code that programs a sort of shop system. It uses GTIN-8. It prints different products, asks for GTIN-8 then asks for the quantity of product. Then print subtotals. Then asks to buy a new product. no prints receipt whereas yes runs the whole function again.

Here is the code:

```
    input("Press enter or any key to see products ")
import csv
total3 = []
with open('product list.csv', newline = '') as f:
    output = csv.reader(f)
    for row in output:
        total3.append(row)
        print("\n","Product GTIN: ", "\t",row[3], "\n","Identification of Product: ","\t",row[0],"\n","Product Description: ","\t","\t",row[1],"\n","Price of Product: ","\t","\t","£",row[2])

newdatalist = []

def function00():
    global total3

    gtin = input("\n Please enter your GTIN number: ")
    if gtin == False or len(gtin) != 8:
            print ("\n Invalid Code!")
            function00()

    for row in total3:
            if row[3] == gtin:
                newdatalist.append(row)

                print("\n",row[0],"\t","My products GTIN: ",row[3],"\t""price for each item: ","\t","£",row[2])
                total3 = input("\n Please enter the quantity of your chosen product: ")

    for row in newdatalist:
        print("\n £",(row[2]),"*",int(total3))
        price = float(row[2])
        total3 = price * int(total3)
    print("\n The total of all products: £",(total3))

    request = (input("\n Would you like a new product: "))
    if request == "yes" or request == "YES" or request ==  "Yes":
        function00()
    else:
        for item in newdatalist:
           print("\n",row[0],"\t My products GTIN: ","\t",str(item[3]),"\t",str(item[1]),"\t","Price for each item: ","\t","\t","£",str(item[2]))
           print("\n Total for every product: £",str(round(total3,2)))
           exit()

function00()
```

Here is the CSV file: [product list.csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lRZQl0iMRsxtv18bjIqOk4-7b4a4ELr_1MdAGQQ2I0s/edit?usp=sharing)

When it is run everything works fine up to when you answer yes to ***'Would you like a new product'***

This happens:

```
line 42, in <module>
function00()
```

and:

```
line 35, in function00
function00()
```

and:

```
    line 20, in function00
    for row in total3:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Can someone plz help me

Thanks,

Comment: In the line `total3 = price * int(total3)` you are setting the variable to a float, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the mistake is in line 30, because you allocate a float `total3 = price * int(total3)` to the variable `total3` and try to iterate over that in line 20 `for row in total3:` at the next run.